# vim mapping key to the command that require argument

Tags: vim

As the title, let say I have to run this command in vim `<command> <argument>`.

In my `.vimrc` I set `let mapleader = ,`

So in normal mode, if I type `,ab` then vim will run command `<command> ab`. if I type `,xyz` then vim will run command `<command> xyz`.

How to do that?

Comment: Give example of the command.

Answer (score 9):

When the arguments are flexible (i.e. you cannot just predefine a set of mappings, as in @svlasov's answer), you can define an incomplete mappings that stays in command-line mode and thereby allows you to complete the command with the `<argument>`. The only downside is that you have to type `<Enter>` at the end (but how would Vim else know when the argument is done?)

#### Example

```
:nnoremap <Leader> :echo<Space>
```

Note that using a pure `<Leader>` mapping is bad; you can't easily have any other mappings; better use something like `<Leader>e`.

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: To be clear: `:echo` is an example for <command>. Or, said differently, if you have the custom command SomeCommand: `:nnoremap <Leader>e :SomeCommand<Space>`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `<command>` with a real one:

```
nmap <leader>ab :<command> ab<CR>
nmap <leader>xyz :<command> xyz<CR>
```